# Convert pandas to txt in google colab

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I have a dataset which called preprocessed_sample in the following format

```
preprocessed_sample.ftr.zstd
```

and I am opening it using the following code

```
df = pd.read_feather(filepath)
```

The output looks something like that

```
index   text
0   0   i really dont come across how i actually am an...
1   1   music has become the only way i am staying san...
2   2   adults are contradicting
3   3   exo are breathing 553 miles away from me. they...
4   4   im missing people that i met when i was hospit...
```

and finally **I would like to save this dataset in a file which called 'examples' and contains all these texts into txt format.**

Update: @Tsingis I would like to have the above lines into txt files, for example the first line 'i really dont come across how i actually am an...' will be a file named 'line1.txt', in the same way all the lines will be txt files into a folder which called 'examples'.

Comment: Somewhat unclear what is the goal. Can you provide example output?

Comment: Then you pretty much need to loop through rows of the `text` column to write each line to separate file using file handler. https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-text-file/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
import pathlib

data_dir = pathlib.Path('./examples')
data_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for i, text in enumerate(df['text'], 1):
    with open(f'examples/line{i}.txt', 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(text)
```

Output:

```
examples/
├── line1.txt
├── line2.txt
├── line3.txt
├── line4.txt
└── line5.txt

1 directory, 5 files
```

`line1.txt`:

```
i really dont come across how i actually am an...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, is to use pandas *built-ins* [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) :

```
import pandas as pd

for row in df.itertuples():
    pd.Series(row.text).to_csv(f"examples/line{row.index+1}.txt",
                               index=False, header=False)
```